# html-webpack-plugin produces redundant tags

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I use [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin) to minify html file using webpack.

Original html file has only `<script src="./app.js"></script>`, but after I minify the file using html-webpack-plugin, it produces `<script src="./app.js"></script><script src="app.js"></script>`. 
It inserts an redundant `<script src="app.js"></script>`.
I've tried every option that [html-minifier](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference) offers, but haven't solved the problem.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

part of my webpack config:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'app/main.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    minify: {
      collapseWhitespace: true,
      removeComments: true,
      removeRedundantAttributes: true,
      removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
      removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
    },
  }),
```

Comment: Docs `The plugin will generate an HTML5 file for you that includes all your webpack bundles in the body using script tags`. So, you can remove `<script src="./app.js"></script>` from template.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in the plugin. You can set it to false and write yourself or you can set it to true etc. and remove your lines from html.

```
inject: false // "body", "head"
```

For more:

```
inject  {Boolean|String}    true    true || 'head' || 'body' || false Inject all assets into the given template or templateContent. When passing true or 'body' all javascript resources will be placed at the bottom of the body element. 'head' will place the scripts in the head element
```